# Couchbase connectivity error in Couchbase connector elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, data-migration, xdcr

In the default-connector.toml, mentioned the domain url along with port no, Able to login to couchbase server through browser from the host specified(http://domain:18091).
In connector It gives the error
hosts = [‘domain:18091’]
Exception in thread “main” com.couchbase.client.core.error.InvalidArgumentException: Specifying 8091 or 18091 in the connection string “domain:8091” is likely not what you want (it would connect to key/value via the management port which does not work). Please omit the port and use “domain” instead.

When port was removed from the hostname It throws error

com.couchbase.client.dcp.deps.io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: Handshake did not complete before deadline. If your seed nodes include a custom port, make sure it’s the port of the KV service which defaults to 11210 (or 11207 for TLS).

Able to connect to elastic cluster by mentioning the port number.

Comment: Cross reference to the Couchbase Forum thread where we're working through the issue: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-connectivity-error-in-couchbase-connector-elastic-search/32237